# "Es gehört schon große Frechheit dazu,..."-meaning of "gehört"

Tags: meaning, verb

I was studying this verb "gehören" and inter alia found the following meaning - "sth. is necessary for sth., i.e. it takes something to do something". Here is an example for illustration purposes

> Es gehört schon große Frechheit dazu, sich so zu benehmen.

I guess my question is how to make sense of this "Es gehört … dazu" structure in a literal sense. Just so I understand the mechanics so to speak.

Comment: English *it takes* is as mysterious. You have to accept it as a fixed phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the verb is not [*gehören*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geh%C3%B6ren) but [*dazugehören*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dazugeh%C3%B6ren). The latter is a separable verb, i.e., the prefix *dazu-* is separated in certain sentence structures, such as in your example sentence

> Es *gehört* schon große Frechheit *dazu* …

This topic is a bit too complex to be outlined here (When/ when not is the prefix separated? Where does the prefix go? And so on.). Therefore, I suggest looking up the keywords *separable verbs* or *trennbare Verben* at a German learning source of your choice.

Comment: Knowing how a separable verb works, and remembering to check for them is another, so it takes practice to get into the habit. Learners generally aren't used to bit of words breaking off and wandering around the sentence on their own.

Comment: @RDBury Learning German requires you to *hunt your prey* - It won't come to you on its own ;)

Comment: Wer auch immer die Antwort abgewertet hat, möge sich bitte erklären – vor allem, wieso er die Antwort für falsch hält.

Comment: I did not downvote the answer, but I do not find it helpful. The question isn't about separable verbs; it's about the meaning of *gehören zu*. How the prepositional object is realised doesn't really matter. You could just as well use *es gehört schon große Frechheit zu so einem Benehmen* as an example.

Comment: @DavidVogt, I disagree. According to his first sentence, the OP already knows roughly what it means (only the title is a bit misleading); but more importantly, he directly writes: *"[...] my question is how to make sense of this "Es gehört … dazu" structure [...]"*

Answer (score 1):

*Gehören* in this use requires a **prepositional object headed by *zu***.

> Meiner Meinung nach gehört große Frechheit **zu so einem Benehmen**.

A literal translation would be *in my opinion, great impudence is required for such behaviour*.

Prepositional objects can be replaced by compounds of *da(r)-* and a preposition called [Präpositionaladverbien](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/207). These can serve several distinct functions. In the given example, *dazu* is an obligatory [Korrelat](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/726) that indicates that a clause (that is to be interpreted as the object of the preposition) follows.

> Meiner Meinung nach gehört große Frechheit **dazu**, sich so zu benehmen.

Alternatively, *Präpositionaladverbien* can be used as pronouns, referring back to something previously mentioned.

> Sprachen lernen ist nicht einfach. **Dazu** gehört Mut.

In that example, *dazu* is interpreted as referring back to the subject of the previous clause: *Zum Sprachenlernen gehört Mut*.

Some other examples.

> Sie wartete **auf einen Anruf**.
> Sie wartete **darauf**, angerufen zu werden.
>
> Er glaubte fest **an den Erfolg seiner Idee**.
> Seine Idee würde Erfolg haben. **Daran** glaubte er fest.